# opencv 2.3.* imread not working

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, windows-7-x64

I cant get imread to work, its same problem as this guy:

[OpenCV imwrite 2.2 causes exception with message "OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension)" on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923296/opencv-imwrite-2-2-causes-exception-with-message-opencv-error-unspecified-erro)

I just dont wannt use the workaround. Anyone know the problem?

Using windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was due to mixing up debugging and release builds.  If building in debug mode, the  debug libs are needed. On unix this dont seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

imread(filename) doesn't load any data if you use release libraries in debug mode. This is weird, I think it should'n happen but actually it does. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries) asking about the reason why this is happening.