# How to save a list of modified images into another folder?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

```py
def gcd(m, n):
  fm = []
for i in range(1, m + 1):
  if (m % i) == 0:
    fm.append(i)
fn = []
for j in range(1, n + 1):
  if (n % i) == 0:
    fn.append(j)
cf = []
for f in fm:
  if f in fn:
  cf.append(f)
return (cf[-1]) for i in pick:
  if scores[i] > min_threshold:
  box = boxes_pixels[i]
box = np.round(box).astype(int)# Draw bounding box.
image = cv2.rectangle(
  image, (box[1], box[0]), (box[3], box[2]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
label = "{}:{:.2f}".format(int(classes[i]), scores[i])

print(classes[i], end = ' ')# Draw label(class index and probability).
draw_label(image, (box[1], box[0]), label)
print(box[1])

print(box[1], box[0], box[3], box[2])# im = image.crop((105, 10, 131, 53))
cropped_image = image[10: 53, 105: 131]
else :
  continue
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)): #Save and display the labeled image.
save_image(image[: ,: , ::-1])
Image(fname, onlyfiles[n])
imshow(image)

def save_image(data, fname = '/home/sunil/image/', swap_channel = True):
  if swap_channel:
  data = data[..., ::-1]
cv2.imwrite(fname, data)
```

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     38 for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
     39 #Save and display the labeled image.
---> 40     save_image(image[:, :, ::-1])
     41     Image(fname,onlyfiles[n])
     42 imshow(image)

in save_image(data, fname, swap_channel)
      2     if swap_channel:
      3         data = data[..., ::-1]
----> 4     cv2.imwrite(fname, data)

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:662: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'

Comment: Perhaps see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868963/cvimwrite-could-not-find-a-writer-for-the-specified-extension

Comment: Please post a minimal code example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at some other questions to see how Stack Overflow works. It's not going to be very well received if you just dump a page of completely uncommented code and a stack trace in a question.

Answer (score 0):

Default filename for your save_image function is `/home/sunil/image/`  looks like a directory and has no extension. Try changing the function definition to

```
def save_image(data, fname = '/home/sunil/image/processed.jpg', swap_channel = True):
```

or maybe, since you want to save multiple files into a same directory, introduce a pattern for file name:

```
def save_image(data, fname = '/home/sunil/image/processed_{n:03d}.jpg', swap_channel = True, n=0):
    if swap_channel:
        data = data[..., ::-1]
        cv2.imwrite(fname.format(n=n), data)
```

then call the function like:

```
save_image(image[: ,: , ::-1], n=n)
```