# YOLOv8 with FASTAPI error could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'

Tags: python, fastapi, torch, yolo, yolov8

I have code to run yolo in fastapi :

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
from ultralytics import YOLO
from PIL import Image
import io

app = FastAPI()
model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml')
model = YOLO('runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt')


@app.post("/detect")
async def detect(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(contents))
    results = model.predict(source=img, save=True)

    return {
            "result": str(results)
        }
```

Show error :

```
[WARNING] Application callable raised an exception
[ERROR] Exception in callback <built-in method _loop_step of builtins.CallbackTaskHTTP object at 0x163b3bd30>
handle: <Handle CallbackTaskHTTP._loop_step>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uvloop/cbhandles.pyx", line 61, in uvloop.loop.Handle._run
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 235, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 161, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "detections/main.py", line 20, in detect
    results = model.predict(source=img, save=True, project="foto_ayam")
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py", line 254, in predict
    return self.predictor.predict_cli(source=source) if is_cli else self.predictor(source=source, stream=stream)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py", line 195, in __call__
    return list(self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs))  # merge list of Result into one
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 35, in generator_context
    response = gen.send(None)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py", line 276, in stream_inference
    self.save_preds(vid_cap, i, str(self.save_dir / p.name))
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py", line 330, in save_preds
    cv2.imwrite(save_path, im0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/xperience/actions-runner/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:730: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'
```

But if parameter save=False everything work well :

```
 results = model.predict(source=img, save=False)
```

I am also has try running detection YOLOv8 without FASTAPI all work well. How to solve this bug ? Thanks

Comment: Seems like you're trying to save a file name without a valid extension, which is what opencv uses to determine the file format to use when writing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, i found a solution :
The problems is asynchronous nature of FastAPI conflicting with the prediction process of YOLOv8.

Solution is to run the YOLOv8 prediction in a synchronous manner, separate from the FastAPI application. You can create a separate function to handle the YOLOv8 prediction and call it within the FastAPI endpoint. Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np

# ...

def run_yolov8_detection(image):
    results = model.predict(source=image, save=True)
    return results


@app.post("/detect")
async def detect(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(contents))

    # Convert PIL Image to NumPy array
    img_np = np.array(img)

    results = run_yolov8_detection(img_np)

    return {
        "result": str(results)
    }
```

By separating the YOLOv8 prediction into a separate function, you can ensure that it runs synchronously and doesn't conflict with the asynchronous nature of FastAPI. This should help in resolving the error you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV need the extension in the name of an image to save it as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868963/cvimwrite-could-not-find-a-writer-for-the-specified-extension) for instance. In you case the name of the output image is automatically inferred by ultralytics' pipeline. According to questions answered in the `model.predict` doc [here](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/), you can try to specify the name and the folder of the output image:

```py
model.predict(source=img, save=True, project='folder/path/', name='name_with_extension.jpg')
```

I didn't try it so please tell me if it works!